# Is it possible to return true even when `docker-compose run` command fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have a script file which contains docker-compose commands

*bootstrap.sh*

```
set -e
#Building docker image
docker-compose build

#Creating Database
docker-compose run --rm app bundle exec rails db:create

#Running Migration
docker-compose run --rm app bundle exec rails db:migrate

#Seeding Database. Running this command twice will throw an error and will terminate the execution
docker-compose run --rm app bundle exec rails db:seed

#Starting Docker containers
docker-compose up
```

Here `bundle exec rails db:seed` command should run only once per database. when I run `sh bootstrap.sh` for the first time it'll work fine but the subsequent run of `sh bootstrap.sh` will fail because I'm trying to seed the same database twice.

So, I need a way to return success even if seeding fails so that my docker container will be up.

for eg.  `docker-compose run --rm app bundle exec rails db:seed || true` something like this. Is it possible to return true when the command passed to the docker-compose fails?

Comment: one thing that you can try to exit with `0` always. `docker-compose run --rm app bundle exec rails db:seed ; exit 0"` and also your command should work fine `docker-compose run --rm app bundle exec rails db:seed || true`

Comment: @Adiii didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails does also come with a handy command which does create, load the schema and seed your database: `db:setup`.

> The bin/rails db:setup command will create the database, load the schema, and initialize it with the seed data.

https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#setup-the-database

In this case, if the database already exists it would return with exit status 0. I think that is a reasonable assumption when the database exists we also assume it is properly seeded.

```sh
set -e
# Building docker image
docker-compose build

# Create db, load the schema and seed it
docker-compose run --rm app bundle exec rails db:setup

# Starting Docker containers
docker-compose up
```

However, in case you need to do more checks (e.g. query the db) before deciding if you need to seed the db or not, you could do a check in your `seeds.rb` script. Something like

```rb
return if User.where(name: "Admin").exists? # If Admin user exists we assume DB is properly seeded
```

Silently swallowing the error in your `bootstrap.sh` script is probably not a good idea, you should prefer to have a safety net in your `seeds.rb` to no error in this case. Otherwise you might end up with corrupt data.